# Integrate and package a ruby module in python application

Tags: python, ruby, python-packaging

I have a custom ruby module which currently I execute through python scripts. But while packaging, I want to package both python and ruby source code together so that end user not need to care about downloading both separately. How to package a ruby module in python application ?

Comment: You can put the ruby file(s) inside your Python package, and call them with a relative path from your Python classes. What did you try exactly?

Comment: Actually I have customized [wraith](http://bbc-news.github.io/wraith) and want to use it with python application. since i need to distribute this python application, it's difficult to ask other users to separately configure all these. Instead i want package this ruby module inside my python application.